# Reducing Bitmap bit-size in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am using C#, and having an image stored in the object Bitmap.

Now I would like to convert this image into 8bit greyscale, then into a 4-bit greyscale image.

Do you have any tips how this can be made?

Answer (score 6):

In the .NET Bitmap formats, there are no such thing as a 8 or 4 bit grayscale image. The supported formats are enumerated by the [PixelFormat enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx). You can, however, create a 4 or 8 bit image by creating a indexed image (8bppIndexed or 4bppIndexed), where each entry in the palette is a greyscale value.

This code takes a Bitmap and creates a copy as a 8bpp indexed image with greyscale values:

```
    public static Bitmap BitmapToGrayscale(Bitmap source)
    {
        // Create target image.
        int width = source.Width;
        int height = source.Height;
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(width,height,PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        // Set the palette to discrete shades of gray
        ColorPalette palette = target.Palette;            
        for(int i = 0 ; i < palette.Entries.Length ; i++)
        {                
            palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(0,i,i,i);
        }
        target.Palette = palette;

        // Lock bits so we have direct access to bitmap data
        BitmapData targetData = target.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width,height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        BitmapData sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width,height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        unsafe
        {
            for(int r = 0 ; r < height ; r++)
            {
                byte* pTarget = (byte*) (targetData.Scan0 + r*targetData.Stride);
                byte* pSource = (byte*) (sourceData.Scan0 + r*sourceData.Stride);
                for(int c = 0 ; c < width ; c++)
                {
                    byte colorIndex = (byte) (((*pSource)*0.3 + *(pSource + 1)*0.59 + *(pSource + 2)*0.11));
                    *pTarget = colorIndex;
                    pTarget++;
                    pSource += 3;
                }
            }
        }

        target.UnlockBits(targetData);
        source.UnlockBits(sourceData);
        return target;
    }
```

In order to make a 4Bpp image instead, you would need to create the *target* with PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed, and then set the ColorPalette to 16 discrete shades of gray. Finally, in the loop you should normalize values 2 be between 0-15 and pack each 2 pixel values into a single byte.

This is the modified code to make a 4bpp greyscale image:

```
    public static Bitmap BitmapToGrayscale4bpp(Bitmap source)
    {
        // Create target image.
        int width = source.Width;
        int height = source.Height;
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(width,height,PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed);
        // Set the palette to discrete shades of gray
        ColorPalette palette = target.Palette;            
        for(int i = 0 ; i < palette.Entries.Length ; i++)
        {
            int cval = 17*i;
            palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(0,cval,cval,cval);
        }
        target.Palette = palette;

        // Lock bits so we have direct access to bitmap data
        BitmapData targetData = target.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width,height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed);
        BitmapData sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width,height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        unsafe
        {
            for(int r = 0 ; r < height ; r++)
            {
                byte* pTarget = (byte*) (targetData.Scan0 + r*targetData.Stride);
                byte* pSource = (byte*) (sourceData.Scan0 + r*sourceData.Stride);
                byte prevValue = 0;
                for(int c = 0 ; c < width ; c++)
                {
                    byte colorIndex = (byte) ((((*pSource)*0.3 + *(pSource + 1)*0.59 + *(pSource + 2)*0.11)) / 16);
                    if (c % 2 == 0)
                        prevValue = colorIndex;
                    else
                        *(pTarget++) = (byte)(prevValue | colorIndex << 4);

                    pSource += 3;
                }
            }
        }

        target.UnlockBits(targetData);
        source.UnlockBits(sourceData);
        return target;
    }
```

Comment: The last part of `BitmapToGrayscale4bpp` has one minor bug: `(byte)(prevValue | colorIndex << 4)` should be `(byte)(prevValue << 4 | colorIndex )`.  The prevValue nibble should come before the colorIndex nibble in the output byte.