# Getting bigger size image while scaling C#

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, image-scaling

I am trying to scale the original image to 50% and 25% and try to download the scaled image in MVC. I am using the below code which was taken from Google search.

```
public byte[] ScaleImageByPercent(byte[] imageBuffer, int Percent)
    {

        using (Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
        {
            using (Image scaleImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
            {
                float scalePercent = ((float)Percent / 100);

                int originalWidth = scaleImage.Width;
                int originalHeight = scaleImage.Height;
                int originalXPoint = 0;
                int originalYPoint = 0;

                int scaleXPoint = 0;
                int scaleYPoint = 0;
                int scaleWidth = (int)(originalWidth * scalePercent);
                int scaleHeight = (int)(originalHeight * scalePercent);

                using (Bitmap scaleBitmapImage = new Bitmap(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                {
                    scaleBitmapImage.SetResolution(scaleImage.HorizontalResolution, scaleImage.VerticalResolution);
                    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(scaleBitmapImage);
                    graphicImage.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    graphicImage.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                    graphicImage.DrawImage(scaleImage,
                        new Rectangle(scaleXPoint, scaleYPoint, scaleWidth, scaleHeight),
                        new Rectangle(originalXPoint, originalYPoint, originalWidth, originalHeight),
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    graphicImage.Dispose();

                    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(scaleBitmapImage, typeof(byte[]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i use 3.4MB image its returning 4.7MB in 50% and even worst in 100% its returning 18 MB.

**EDIT**:
After getting the byte array i am downloading the image using below code. After downloading while i check the file size in disk its showing bigger size.

```
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(scaledBytes));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
```

Am i doing the scaling correctly?. Which one i need to change get the lower size image while scaling using above functionality.

Comment: Are you comparing the size of the two bytes arrays or the size of the file on disk? Keep in mind that when you i.e. load a JPG file that is let's say 500Kb, it gets decompressed in memory, resulting in a much larger byte array (at least 32bits * pixels width * pixels height). Therefore you can get a "several megabytes" bytes array from a very small JPG file (that could be the case that you see with the 100% resize). That effectively would match your values: percent 50% = resulting image being 1/4 of the original, and 4.7Mb is 1/4 of 18Mb.

Comment: @Leo. I am comparing the size of the file on disk. Please see my edits.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. As I say your code just works perfectly, it's a matter of image compression. Give it a try and please let me know!

Comment: @Leo I have tried your code by saving the byte as image. But still i am passing the HttpResponseMessage content as stream i am getting the same result. And i am calling it as Web API, in my code i dont have the virtual path or outputpath. so i am doing as <a href="api/Control/DownloadImage" download="filename.jpg"/>. and i am not sure i doing correctly.:(

Comment: I see. What happens then is that you are actually telling the browser to download a file named "filename.jpg", therefore you'll get a file with a ".jpg" extension on your disk, but the actual content of the file is an uncompressed bitmap (that causes the size to be larger than the original file that I suppose was a proper jpg instead). Then the software you use to view the image content (maybe the browser itself) relying on the file header rather than on its extension shows the content anyway. I'll try to edit my answer as soon as I get to my pc. Meanwhile try to save to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am also trying..

Comment: Edited my answer, please give it a try!

Comment: Hi Ramesh did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, I believe it's just a matter of image compression, basically you are pushing your byte array to your output stream as is, while you should save it as a jpeg. In my example I use a FileStream for simplicity, in your case you should use your output stream.
Give this a try (just drop any Jpg file on the compiled executable):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(args[0]);
            byte[] originalImage = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            byte[] resizedImage = ScaleImageByPercent(originalImage, 50);
            using (Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(resizedImage))
            {
                using (Image scaleImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
                {
                    string outputPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                outputPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(outputPath, $"{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)}_resized.jpg");
                using (FileStream outputFile = System.IO.File.Open(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    scaleImage.Save(outputFile, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static byte[] ScaleImageByPercent(byte[] imageBuffer, int Percent)
    {

        using (Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
        {
            using (Image scaleImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
            {
                float scalePercent = ((float)Percent / 100);

                int originalWidth = scaleImage.Width;
                int originalHeight = scaleImage.Height;
                int originalXPoint = 0;
                int originalYPoint = 0;

                int scaleXPoint = 0;
                int scaleYPoint = 0;
                int scaleWidth = (int)(originalWidth * scalePercent);
                int scaleHeight = (int)(originalHeight * scalePercent);

                using (Bitmap scaleBitmapImage = new Bitmap(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                {
                    scaleBitmapImage.SetResolution(scaleImage.HorizontalResolution, scaleImage.VerticalResolution);
                    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(scaleBitmapImage);
                    graphicImage.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    graphicImage.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                    graphicImage.DrawImage(scaleImage,
                        new Rectangle(scaleXPoint, scaleYPoint, scaleWidth, scaleHeight),
                        new Rectangle(originalXPoint, originalYPoint, originalWidth, originalHeight),
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    graphicImage.Dispose();

                    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(scaleBitmapImage, typeof(byte[]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here it is the result:

[image]

EDIT: 
Ok for the webapi interface try doing like this:

```
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        using (Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(resizedImage))
        {
            using (Image scaleImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    scaleImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that we can reduce size of image by change **PixelFormat** type.

You can refer to this [Reducing Bitmap bit-size in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703947/reducing-bitmap-bit-size-in-c-sharp)